# Collaborative brainstorming tool

Tags: gratis, collaboration

In the good old days, when you could meet with a group of people, we would often brainstorm using large sheets of paper and post-it or sticky notes.

Seeing meetings these days are mostly limited to MS Teams or Zoom it's hard to replicate such a brainstorming environment, as you would all interrupt each other talking and the whole conversation becomes a mess.

I'm looking for a tool to facilitate this kind of brainstorming.

I prefer a tool that:

1. Supports about a dozen people collaborating at the same time
2. Is easy to install / register to / log in to
3. Participants can place and organise sticky notes
4. Participants can rank/vote on placed notes to share their preferred options.

Support for conversation isn't needed, as that can be handled through MS Teams or Zoom. Regarding cost, a free(mium) tool would be great.

I think a web-app would be easiest, as I need to use it with people from within, and outside the organisation. Otherwise, it should be compatible with at least Mac and Windows.

Comment: Check out [Microsoft Whiteboard](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-whiteboard/about/)

Answer (score 2):

So ofcourse I did some research myself following the question I posted.
I ended up chosing [Miro](https://miro.com/).

Miro is a freemium webapp that lets you collaborate on whiteboards. For my situation I chose the "Consultant plan" [(at $12/month)](https://miro.com/pricing/) as that allowed me to invite anonymous users to participate in editing the board we wanted to work on. Saving them the hassle of registering, and joining my team. In which case this could be done for free.

I think the app is really intuitive to use, at least for using the Sticky-notes scenario I described in the question. Besides brainstorming like this it offers many more options, that are showcased on their homepage. These include:

- Meetings & Workshops
- Ideation & Brainstorming
- Research & Design
- Agile Workflows
- Strategy & Planning
- Mapping & Diagramming

Answer (score 0):

You could also give [notion.so](http://notion.so) a try.

Here are some templates that I found that may suit your needs:
https://www.redgregory.com/notion/2021/11/1/6-notion-templates-for-ideation-and-solutions